# Executing Windows based admin tools without Windows?

Tags: windows-update, livecd, boot-cd

Is there a boot CD / USB stick OS or similar which I can use to execute basic admin tools designed for Windows?

For example, I'd like to flash firmware on a RAID card, and the tools the vendor supplies all rely on Windows, but I am running Linux! So far I've use a FreeDOS based stick to execute stuff that's DOS based, but some tools die with "This program is not meant to be run from the command line" or similar. Any ideas? Any basic boot CDs or such? Is my only resort to install a free HD, install Windows, etc. just to flash some firmware??!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use WinPE, available on [Windows AIK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=10333).

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like a Live Disc/USB drive of Windows? You can find one at [LiveCD.com](http://www.livecd.com/).
Try it out.